# Get an ontology IRI

Tags: owl, ontology, owl-api

When we wanna create or load an ontology we use this line of code `IRI ontologyIRI = IRI.create("http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/ontologyName");` So, what should I use to get it as an output?

I tried with this function `IRI documentIRI = manager.getOntologyDocumentIRI(ontology);` but it retunrs the location of the ontology file, something like this `file:/Users/.../Desktop/ontologyname.owl`.

Instead of it, I need the one written like this :

```
http://owl.man.ac.uk/2005/07/sssw/ontologyName
```

Please, If you have any ideas... Thank you

Comment: I don't get the question. Do you want to have the IRI from where you loaded the ontology? Or the ontology IRI that's part of an OWL document? Both are totally different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OWLOntology o = ...
IRI iri = o.getOWLOntologyID().getOntologyIRI().get();
```

This returns the IRI that the ontology is identified with; note - this might not be the same IRI that you loaded the ontology from. The resolvable IRI in your example might point at an ontology declaring a different IRI for itself (it is, in that sense, a document IRI).

Comment: Very close, the actual call is: 


OWLOntology o = …; 
IRI iri = o.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI().get()

Comment: Depends on the owlapi version. The version 5 answer already exists below.

Answer (score 1):

With OWLAPI-5, you can get the ontology IRI using the method:

```
ont.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI().get()
```

Here you are an example:

```
OWLOntologyManager man = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
OWLOntology ont = man.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(IRI.create("file:/Users/.../Desktop/ontologyname.owl"));
IRI yourIRI = ont.getOntologyID().getOntologyIRI().get();
String yourOntoURI = yourIRI.toString();
```

Example source from owlapi: [owlapi-github-examples](https://github.com/phillord/owl-api/blob/master/contract/src/test/java/org/coode/owlapi/examples/Examples.java) (line 1115)